# Implementing Batch Update in Kendo UI GRID not work

Tags: web-services, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-grid

While trying to perform batch update, I am not able to post values to MVC WEB API controller neither I am getting Record IDs in mu PUT controller.
I have already visited some of the links egarding same problem but got no solution.

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      debugger;
      var webapiUrl = (My webapi);

      dataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                        type: "json",
                        transport: {
                            read:  {
                                url: webapiUrl + api/GetProductsByShipID/1",
                                contentType: "application/json",

                            },
                            update: {
                                url: webapiUrl + api/OpportunityProducts/1",

                                contentType: "application/json",
                                type: "PUT"
                            },
                            destroy: {
                                url: webapiUrl + /api/OpportunityProducts/",
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                type: "DELETE"
                            },
                            create: {
                                url: webapiUrl + /api/OpportunityProducts/",
                                contentType: "application/json",
                                type: "POST"
                            },
                            parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                                if (operation !== "read") {
                                    return options;
                                }
                            }

                        },
                        batch: true,
                        pageSize: 10,
                        schema: {
                            model: {
                                id: "ID",
                                fields: {
                                    ID: { editable: false, nullable: true },
                                    ProductDesc: { type: "string" },
                                    Quantity: {type: "number"},
                                    UnitPrice: { type: "number"}
                                }
                            }

                    });

                $("#grid").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource: dataSource,
                    navigatable: true,
                    pageable: true,
                    toolbar: ["create", "save", "cancel"],
                    columns: [
                        "ProductName",
                        { field: "ProductDesc", title: "Product Desc"},
                        { field: "Quantity", title: "Quantity" },
                        { field: "UnitPrice", width: 120 },
                        { command: "destroy", title: "&nbsp;", width:150 }],
                    editable: true
                });
            });
        </script>
```

Comment: so what is being sent over to your api when you inspect the body. using something like fiddler. Also in your code example it looks like you are missing an opening quote around the `/api/OpportunityProducts/`

Comment: Thanks for your comment below is the answer to this question. And that quote miss was a typo while copying url here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well after some workaround, late night I was able to modify parameterMap  section of my kendo grid which lead me to expected output.

This is how I updated my parameterMap section...

**Previous**

```
parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                        if (operation !== "read") {
                            return options;
                        }
                    }
```

**Updated**

```
 parameterMap: function (options, operation) {
                            debugger;
                            if (operation !== "read" && options.models) {
                    var webapiUrl = (my webapi);
                      var i = 0;
                      for (i = 0; i < options.models.length; i++) {
                          $.ajax({
                              cache: false,
                              async: true,
                              type: "PUT",
                              url: webapiUrl + "/api/OpportunityProducts/" + options.models[i].Id,
                          data: {

                           ID: options.models[i].ID,
                           ProductDesc: options.models[i].ProductDesc,
                                  Quantity: options.models[i].Quantity
                           },

                              success: function (data) {

                              },

                              error: function (jqXHR, exception) {

                                  alert(exception);

                              }

                          });

                      }
```